# Android emulator has old versions of application

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am testing my Android application on an emulator through Android Studio. A month back I setup my emulator, did some tests, etc. I have changes to the codebase during the last month, have tested on a device, and want to test against the emulator because it has an earlier API than my device.

When I run the emulator it has an earlier version of the application. For instance I have changed the app icon but in the emulator the icon is the default Android one.

Are there specific steps I have to take to push my updated version to the emulator?

Comment: Just start the emulator and run your project?

Comment: Increment android:versionCode in your manifest. That being said, that doesn't always work, so then use Dalija's suggestion in that case. If the icon doesn't update after that, then there might a problem with the drawable itself, or the drawable folders of various densities you used to put your icon in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open AVD Manager in AS: `Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager` and select `Wipe Data` from pull down menu on desired AVD. That will reset your AVD to initial state and remove any installed versions of your app.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I actually uninstalled the app via the emulator, but this is essentially the same thing. Accepted